# New alkaline batteries with 10-year shelf life—what's changed?

Tags: batteries, battery-chemistry

I'm finding that some new alkaline batteries, such as the new Duracell Duralock and Energizer Power Seal batteries, have a shelf life of 10 years.  Most other alkaline batteries have a shelf life of 7 years.

How is the chemistry or structure of these new alkaline batteries different, and how does it affect performance and battery life under various loads compared to older batteries?  Google hasn't been very helpful here.

Comment: Is their definition of shelf life the same? How far can the cell be discharged to call it end-of-shelf-life?

Comment: Shelf-life, as the name implies, means how long the battery can be stored before its first use.  It doesn't necessarily have anything to do with its performance after it is put under load.

Comment: The chemistry could have changed in ways that impact load performance.

Answer (score 8):

The Duralock battery has improved alkaline cells (improved purity of actual chemical ingredients) not only this but the Duralock battery protects the anode and cathode with separators that limit power transfer when the battery is not in use. On top of this, it has a sort of triple corrosion protection that surrounds the contents in an acid resistant, anti-corrosive exterior. Therefore ensuring shelf life.

Although probably not a complete answer,
Hope this helps

Comment: How does this impact performance under load?

Comment: http://news.pg.com/press-release/pg-corporate-announcements/duracell-reveals-its-biggest-battery-news-creation-iconic-c

Comment: "...starts with powerful ingredients that are as pure as 24 karat gold ..." Which is an odd way to try and say "99.95%" or something (depending on the mass of the material they are talking about).